# Android In-App Purchases, protection from piracy

Tags: android, ssl, in-app-purchase

I have read [Can In-App Purchase Prevent Software Piracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599654/can-in-app-purchase-prevent-software-piracy) recently.

It's talking about using ssl etc. for protecting apps from piracy.
I'm planning to do something different, but i'm not sure if it's enough.
User gonna sign up for my services in app, and then when user wants to activate some paid stuff.
User will pay for it and when the purchase completed,the app will write onto sql database about activating something.
And when the app connected to internet,it's gonna get the data of whether something is activated or not,if something activated,it will enable it. My app works with internet, so most probably checking process will always work.
And i will send device properties onto server,so i won't allow user to use the application with same username and password more than 3 devices.

The Question is, is it enough? my server won't use ssl or something but sql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely more of a philosophical question. When it comes to security in general, there is never enough. It comes down to risk-assessment.

Your situation has three-facets:

1. Purchase authentication - which if you are doing it right, Google has created a practically secure solution. If you don't even call the server unless the purchase is authenticated then SSL will do nothing to help make this facet more secure.
2. Limiting devices - this is where you can benefit from SSL. The risk of not having SSL, is if you have someone smart enough to spoof your server and perform a [Man-in-the-Middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Which if that was to happen, they only gain the ability to access the content with more than the proposed 3 devices.
3. Content protection - if the content on the server is what the customer is paying to get access to, that can possibly be a target. Someone may try to spoof a device and access your server content. SSL may or may not help with this, depending on server-side implementation.

My two-cents*: You can spend days/weeks/months implementing a solution, or you can put a practical (less-secure) solution and focus more on your user experience. i.e. What is more important, total security or the number of users and their satisfaction?

*Unless your content needs protection because of contractual obligations.

Comment: i will back up server everyday automatically, so if i find out something wrong i can restore from backup. and atleast that will gonna protect me from free apk files on the net?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the "free" apk files out there. If they are just redistributing the apk, your code should be there and so will the license checks.